# PVCS deleting a file from the project

Tags: pvcs, serena

I have a java project stored in Serena Dimensions, and edited from eclipse.
When trying to delete, i get the message:

Delete Item - Cor0005207E Error: Item <> is included in a release or archive Baseline.

Which is correct.  I don't want to eradicate the file from history, I just want it not to show up in eclipse from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to delete? A file, or the whole eclipse project?

If you're just trying to delete a file, you can do that from Eclipse. Delete the file, go to Team -> Synchronize with Repository, and deliver the deletion. (If you're using PROJECTS and not STREAMS, make sure you undo your checkout of the file, first).

If you're trying to delete a whole eclipse project, you should be able to do that from the Desktop Client. Right click the .ecl file in the Folders and Items view, click Relate/Unrelate, and unrelate it from your CM Project (If you are using Streams, it's slightly more complicated; see below).

Comment: I am trying to delete the file.  I, unfortunately, have to do it from the Desktop Client.  I'll accept your answer, even if I'm not entirely sure